# how to add click event on marker in leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm trying to add a click event for each marker in for a loop. Please see the js code.

I'm developing a map with multiple clickable markers with leaflets and OpenStreetMap.

```
var markers = [];

for (var i=0; i < selectedLocations.length; i++) 
{
  var image = selectedLocations[i].properties.image;
  var image_alt = selectedLocations[i].properties.image_alt;
  var name = selectedLocations[i].properties.name;
  var coords = selectedLocations[i].geometry.coordinates;
//set content in the infoWindow 
  const content = `<div id="infoWindow" style="width:150px; margin:2px;">
    <h2 style="font-size:14px; text-align:center;">${name}</h2>
    <img src="${image}" alt="${image_alt}" height="100px" width="150px">
    </div>`;

  markers[i] = L.marker([coords[1],coords[0]]).bindPopup(content).addTo(map);   
  markers[i].on('click',function(i){
    console.log(i);//in this code, the output i is always the length of the array
  });
}
```

I'm trying to call a function based on the value i. But whichever marker I click, i is always the length of the array instead of the current I value.

Answer (score 1):

@Denis answer is very elegant (I did not know this syntax)

The 'classical' way would be to add a property to your marker and fetch the value from the event target

```
markers[i] = L.marker([coords[1],coords[0]]).bindPopup(content).addTo(map); 
markers[i].id = i;  
markers[i].on('click',function(event){
  console.log(event.target.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow function for click handled. The difference is that is will record `i`'s value at the moment of function definition.

```
  markers[i].on('click',()=> {
    console.log(i);//in this code, the output i is always the length of the array
  });
```